# access_token without an app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

According to latest change in Facebook, even public feed can't be access without access_token.

I was using http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed in one of my website.

I haven't created any app in Facebook. What would be simplest way to get access_token, possibly using my Facebook account only and not creating any app or so.

So in conclusion I want to use http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed. For that I want to generate the access_token in the simplest way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to get an access_token, and the only one I know, **is to register an app**. Why do you resist that? It will take you 2 minutes to fill out a form.